# Making an alias for `tree -P '*name*'`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tree

I'm creating an `alias` for the following command with the `tree` program:

```
tree -P '*name*'
```

This **works exactly as I want. But when I create an alias for this command, the command behaves differently: It only prints directories and not files.**

#### In `.bash_aliases`

```
function tree_seek {
tree -P '*$1*' 
}

alias treeseek='tree_seek'
```

**Why does the alias `treeseek name` does not do the same as `tree -P '*name*'`.**

Comment: @artistoex Could you elaborate on that? From what I can tell, this is no different from the deleted answer you commented on, since double-quoted asterisks aren't subject to expansion, so `tree -P "*$1*"` should work as well.

Comment: Indeed, using double quotes like `Daniel Beck` said works as well. Could you post this as a seperate answer?

Comment: Aliases don't handle arguments, use a shell function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash, [single quotes won't interpolate anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash). Try using double quotes in your function instead:

```
function tree_seek() {
  tree -P "*$1*" 
}

alias treeseek='tree_seek'
```

Comment: @daniel-beck: Sorry, I certainly didn't mean to hijack your answer. I didn't see your comment before I posted my answer.

Comment: +1 for finding out and for your apologies to Daniel Beck.